# Get average rating using sql

Tags: java, sql

I have a Java program that rates movies that are in my database, what I'd like to do is use sql to get the average rating of the movies,but not an overall average from all of them. For example if 3 different people rate the same movie id like to be able to get that average, but the list would have lots of movies rated a couple of times from different users.  So how could I get all the averages from all the movies rated by different people?  So far I can only get an overall average.

The table would be [FILM   EMAIL   RATING]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and update your question with more specific details. Show table schema, sample data etc.  Also, show any SQL you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give the schema. So i guessed the columns with two tables :

```
SELECT name, round( (film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) , 2) as avg_rating
FROM 
( 
   SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, film_id, 
   SUM(rating) as film_total_ratings 
   FROM  `rating` GROUP BY film_id 
) AA LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT id, name FROM `film`  ) BB ON BB.id = AA.film_id
```

Alternately for one table as you mentioned:

```
SELECT FILM, (film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) as avg_rating 
FROM( 
SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, FILM, 
   SUM(RATING) as film_total_ratings 
   FROM  avg GROUP BY FILM 
) TMP_FILM
```

Comment: Hi i have no schema just colums, tried the above code but im getting errors. My table is called avg and my colums are FILM  EMAIL RATING

Comment: one table only? are you new to sql?

Comment: Yes very but i am using it in a java project and have every thing working exept this

Comment: you need to design the db first for not to get redundant data. However answer update. If this is not working, Mention your database(oracle or mysql or others) and paste sample rows of your table